# Facing such error while run UDF in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I try to run following code but facing such error.

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    def retrieve_night_flag(row):
        x=row
        if x >= night_time['start_time'] and x < night_time['end_time']:
            return 'NIGHT'
        elif x >= day_time['start_time'] and x < day_time['end_time']:
            return 'DAY' 
        else:
            return 'EVE'
        
    UDF_NAME = udf(lambda row: retrieve_night_flag(row),StringType())
    df_source3 =df_source2 .withColumn('night_flag', UDF_NAME(col('hour_stamp')))
```

error we found:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o765.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 38.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 35) (INNOLX4356.itte.com executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Error from python worker:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
          mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
          __import__(pkg_name)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question.

Comment: Is your Python version 3.5? I think Spark is compatible with 3.7 and up